# AWS Windows AMI and SIDs

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a master image with all the IIS and SQL2k8 config, DBs, etc.
It was bundled and turned into a private AMI.

Launching an instance with this new AMI breaks the security settings because the IUSR_ and SQL2k8 admin accounts have different SID and different machine names.

What's is the best way of getting around it?

I would like to clone the web server machine without reconfiguring it for every instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're going to have to do some scripting as part of the rollout, you may find the [NewSID](http://www.filecluster.com/System-Utilities/Other-Utilities/Download-NewSID.html) utility helpful.